# adding running total to a query in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

In SQL terms, I have the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Students
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    Age int NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO Students VALUES (1,'A', 14 );
INSERT INTO Students VALUES (2,'B', 12 );
INSERT INTO Students VALUES (3,'C', 13 );
```

I can run the following query:

```sql
SELECT Id, Name, Age,
SUM (Age) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS RunningAgeTotal
FROM Students
```

to get:

| name | age | runningagetotal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 14 | 14 |
| B | 12 | 26 |
| B | 13 | 39 |

as explained here for [example](https://codingsight.com/calculating-running-total-with-over-clause-and-partition-by-clause-in-sql-server/).

Can I do a similar thing in Google sheet?

I tried:

```sql
SELECT blah, blah, SUM(C) OVER (ORDER BY A) AS 'Total'
WHERE ...
```

Where `C` is the value I want a running total for, and A is the ID, powered by `ROW()`, but I am getting:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered "  "OVER "" at line 2, column 8. Was expecting one of:  "where" ... "group" ... "pivot" ... "order" ... "skipping" ... "limit" ... "offset" ... "label" ... "format" ... "options" ... "," ... "*" ... "+" ... "-" ... "/" ... "%" ...

which suggests `OVER` is not supported in google sheets. is there any other way of doing this in google sheets that would not involve creating a secondary column of data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that there is no 'OVER' clause in Google Sheets Query - the options available are limited compared with other implementations of SQL like T-SQL.

The answer is rather counter-intuitive. You can exploit the behaviour of the SUMIF function, which allows you to re-evaluate the sum for each of a list of values in the 'criterion' part of the function call. If this is the row number, you can get a separate sum up to and including each row of the data which gives you the running total:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A<>"",sumif(row(A2:A),"<="&row(A2:A),B2:B),))
```

[image]

Unfortunately this isn't available in SUMIFS so the functionality is rather limited.

If you need something more flexible, as far as I know the only alternative is to use multiplication by a triangular matrix, which is rather expensive in terms of resources.

Answer (score 2):

as of now, this cant be done inside QUERY - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

you will need to apply it like this:

```
={QUERY({A2:B}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"), 
 INDEX(MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(INDIRECT("Z1:Z"&COUNTA(QUERY({A2:B}, 
 "select sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"))))<=
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("Z1:Z"&COUNTA(QUERY({A2:B}, 
 "select sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"))))))*QUERY({A2:B}, 
 "select sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''")), 
 SIGN(1+N(INDIRECT("Z1:Z"&COUNTA(QUERY({A2:B}, 
 "select sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''")))))))}
```

[image]