# Convert =SUM(A1:A) to arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, sum, formula

How this formula can be converted in to array =SUM(A1:A) so that I won't drag the formula to the last cell.

I tried =Arrayformula(sum(A1:A)) but it only works on the cell where the formula is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adding running total to a query in Google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67360218/adding-running-total-to-a-query-in-google-sheets)

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula-

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A,MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(A2:A)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A)))*A2:A),SIGN(A2:A)), IFERROR(1/0)))
```

Another easier formula-

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(B2:B),(SUMIF(ROW(B2:B),"<="&ROW(B2:B),B2:B)),))
```

Read this [article](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/running-total/) for details-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you attempt for cumulative sum try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(ROW(A1:A10), "<="&ROW(A1:A10), A1:A10))
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add more condition here or use `SUMIFS()`?

Comment: @Harun24HR no and no. for more conditions is best MMULT or QUERY