# Running SUM with ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a list of values per day and I want, for each day, to sum the last 7 days using an array formula.
Basically, I want to use this formula

=SUM(A1:A7) inside an ARRAYFORMULA but I can't get it to work.

Theoretically it should look something like

ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(B1:B:B7:B)) which of course doesn't work.

*Note:* the formula must be at the top row, since new data is added daily so row 2 of today will become row 3 tomorrow. The solution therefor must fit the top cell of the column.

I created a sheet with an example. Col A is dates, Col B is values Col C is the manual sum of the 7 days just as a reference

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jsC5mN2Bdq5a1u2GjoufTTPmSjyurOPd1YXQEv_AGfk/edit#gid=0

Comment: You may get benefit from this article. https://stackoverflow.com/q/71688149/5514747

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have entered the following in cell D2:

```
=flatten(
  index(
   query(
    if(
     (sequence(counta(B2:B))<sequence(1,counta(B2:B))+7)* 
     (sequence(counta(B2:B))>=sequence(1,counta(B2:B))),
     B2:B,
    ),
    "select sum(Col"&join("), sum(Col",sequence(counta(B2:B)))&")"),
  2))
```

Comment: Super solution. What about performance for large dataset.

Comment: Very nice solution. However, part of the reason I wanted it solved with ARRAYFORMULA is that I can add the formula at the top row. This is because the new date is added daily in row 2 so if I don't have the formula at the top row it will not effect new data. I'm adding an edit to the question.

Comment: @Harun24HR, I haven't tested it, but this type of two-dimensional comparison is generally pretty bad for large datasets. Normally, we could use FILTER/INDIRECT to improve performance but it shouldn't be necessary in this case.

Comment: @Tom, you can use [curly brackets arrays](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en) to put the formula in header (see updated formula). But if you're going to add new rows below row 1, you'll also have to use INDIRECT for the ranges. `B2:B -> INDIRECT("B2:B")`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this old-school method:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(isnumber(B:B),sumif(row(B:B),"<"&row(B:B)+7,B:B)-sumif(row(B:B),"<"&row(B:B),B:B),))
```

[image]

Or better this to include a header:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(B:B="",,if(isnumber(B:B),sumif(row(B:B),"<"&row(B:B)+7,B:B)-sumif(row(B:B),"<"&row(B:B),B:B),"Running Total")))
```

Comment: This is a great solution, thanks!