# Formula for Column to Keep a Running Balance of Transactions is Producing Additional Decimal Places

Tags: google-sheets, floating-point, array-formulas, currency, decimal-point

***Update: Solved**

> I've learned that it's not really a problem other than to annoy me. See additional blockquote notes for more info. If it still bugs you, I posted a solution.

**Original Question:**

I have a checking account register sheet to track transactions and to keep a running balance. For example...

| Check # | Date | Desc. | Amount | Cleared | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 12/01 | Start | $50.00 | Yes | $50.00 |
|  | 12/02 | Dep. | $10.00 | Yes | $60.00 |
| 123 | 12/03 | Store | -$10.54 | Yes | $49.46 |

The 'Balance' column is to add or subtract the amount from the previous transaction above, so that every new transaction shows the current balance at the time for that line. However, I've tried two formulas and they both result in many of the results having extra decimal places. They display correctly since I have the column formatted as currency, but the data stored often has extra decimal places.

For example: $49.46 will display correctly when formatted as currency, but the actual data produced behind that inside the cell is often something like 49.455 (.xxx.) or 49.45500000001 (.xxx0000000x) or 49.455999999999 (.xxx999999999).

> I found three 'Amount' entries that that had typos with three decimal places (.xxx). Fixing those fixed the 'Balance' entries that had three decimal places (.xxx). After fixing the typos, (.xxx0000000x) went to (.xx0000000000x), and (.xxx999999999) went to (.xx9999999999x). But those long (.xx0000000000x) and (.xx9999999999x) entries are still there.

I've done some searching for what might cause this and found that it might be due to Floating Point errors. I only skimmed it but kind of get what that is now.

> I've since learned this is normal and is indeed a result of Floating Point (FP) arithmetic. More below.

Both formulas I've tried...

```
={"Balance";
 ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF( ISBLANK(C2:C)*ISBLANK(D2:D),,
   SCAN( 0,D2:D,
    LAMBDA(
     runningTotal,
     currentAmount,
     runningTotal+currentAmount
    )
   )
  )
 )
}
```

```
={"Balance";
 ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF( ISBLANK(C2:C)*ISBLANK(D2:D),,
   SUMIF(
    ROW(D2:D),
    "<="&ROW(D2:D),
    D2:D
   )
  )
 )
}
```

I have three questions regarding this...

1. Will this actually affect the accuracy of the math down to the absolute penny over the course of thousands of transactions? (I have close to 9,000.) **Solved*
2. If so, what is the best way to fix this? **Solved*
3. Even if it remains 100% accurate, is there a simple fix so that it doesn't irritate me so much? Haha ****See solution posted as an answer***

Thank you in advance!

Here is a test sheet that demonstrates the issue...
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YCUReqisi92prqhdb0aRgRaZmoaileqhdtHXYB0UVTY/edit?usp=sharing

The problematic cells are highlighted in orange. They display correctly on the surface because of the currency formatting, but when you click on the cell, they have extra decimal points within the data of the cell.

> As was pointed out in the comments below, Floating Point (FP) arithmetic or operations (*in cases like this, sometimes called Floating Point errors because they appear to be errors*) are not actually errors at all.
>
> The longer decimal places, (.xx0000000000x) and (.xx9999999999x), are just a part of how FP does its thing. I've learned that it's benign and does not affect the actual final math.
>
> For more info, here's the link that was shared: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)
>
> If it still irritates you as much as it did me, my semi-cosmetic fix (posted as an answer below) will do the trick. Thanks everyone!

Comment: I took you data and both formula and couldn't reproduce your problem. displayed values are 49.46, and when the number of decimal places are increased, the value remains as 49.46. Is there something about your spreadsheet that you have left out of the question? any other thoughts?

Comment: Related question: [adding running total to a query in Google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67360603/1330560) The solution by  @TomSharpe is simple and doesn't distort any balances. This is the equivalent formula for your data. `=ArrayFormula(if(D2:D<>"",sumif(row(D2:D),"<="&row(D2:D),D2:D),))`

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, that formula had the same affect. I have around 9,000 rows so it could be the sheer volume that is affecting this. I found a solution by using the ROUND function. I -think- that should solve it. Hopefully.

Comment: `I have around 9,000 rows` This is something that might have been important to include in the question., OTOH, I don't believe that this should have any effect on the formula. If the values in "Amount" column are 2 digit decimals, then there is zero reason why the running total should be anything other than a 2 digit decimal result. There MUST be another specific factor.

Comment: As a matter of interest, have you done any "old-school" trouble shooting to identify which row(s) are cause the decimal error. For example, `=abs(D2)-roundup(abs(D2),2)`, copy down 9,000 rows, apply conditional formatting to every formula "not equal to 0", then page down looking for highlighted cells.

Comment: What is the largest amount or balance in any row?

Comment: @Tedinoz: Re “If the values in "Amount" column are 2 digit decimals, then there is zero reason why the running total should be anything other than a 2 digit decimal result”: Google Sheets uses the IEEE-754 binary64 format. That format is incapable of representing numbers whose decimal numerals end in two digits after the decimal point except for .00, .25, .50, and .75. All other numbers incur rounding errors. So there is non-zero reason why the running total should be anything other than a two-digit decimal result. (Some rounding errors are concealed by kludges in the spreadsheet software.)

Comment: Rounding errors with 9000 rows adding and subtracting numbers with two digits after the decimal point should not produce visible rounding errors unless some numbers are in the billions. That suggests some of the Amounts are not actually numbers with two digits after the decimal point. Are any of them calculated rather than typed in? Could there be typos in some of them?

Comment: Thank you for all the feedback! I went through the sheet with some conditional formatting to look for cells with text or any entries with more than three decimal places. I found three cells with an extra decimal place accidentally entered in. I fixed those but it didn't fix the issue. So I made an edited copy of the sheet (removed private info and changed most of the numbers) and shared it in the original post. I hope it helps. Thanks again!

Comment: Where is the problem? Your post says there are cells with numbers “like 49.455”. I looked for Balance cells that differed from their rounding to two decimal places by more than .0001 and did not find any.

Comment: The problematic cells are highlighted in orange. I may not have been clear enough in the OP but they display correctly on the surface, but when you click on the cell, they have extra decimal points within the data of the cell.

Comment: Fixing the few entries I found that had three decimal places (.xxx) seems to have fixed the balance entries that had three decimal places (.xxx). But the long .xx0000000000x entries are still there.

Comment: I updated the OP with clarifications and updates.

Comment: Related question: [Google Sheet yields infinitesimal number as remainder of an integer/whole number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74542790/1330560) More information about this subject than one ever wanted/needed to know :)

Comment: There is nothing here. The cells with numbers like “.455” were due to typos. The cells with numbers like “.…00000001” or “.…999999997” have [ordinary floating-point rounding errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: In 40 years, I haven't had this problem (or not that I can recall :). But this quote from @player0 who I greatly admire : `floating point operation is introduced in your sheet with every numeric value you store in any cell. its the way how numeric numbers are stored not the result of users operation`

Comment: Even with the typos fixed, it was irritating me. I assumed a Floating Point "Error" meant there was an "error" in a more traditional sense. Now that I understand more what FPEs or FPOs are and that they're not really avoidable in some circumstances, I'll just live with it using my cosmetic-only "irritation" fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments to the original question, Floating Point (FP) arithmetic or operations (*in cases like this, sometimes called Floating Point errors because they appear to be errors*) are not actually errors at all.

The longer decimal places, (.xx0000000000x) and (.xx9999999999x), are just a part of how FP does its thing. I've learned that it's benign and does not affect the actual final math.

For more info, here's the link that was shared: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

If it still irritates you as much as it did me, my semi-cosmetic fix (posted here) will do the trick. It makes it so that the data produced in the actual cell (behind the two-decimal-place 'displayed' result) is now also at two-decimal-places.

All I did was incorporate the ROUND function into each formula. I had listed two formulas that I attempted to use in the original question. Here are both of those options with the ROUND function added. (The LAMBDA version seems to work more efficiently with less load on the sheet.)

```
={"Balance";
 ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF( ISBLANK(C2:C)*ISBLANK(D2:D),,
   SCAN( 0,D2:D,
    LAMBDA(
     runningTotal,
     currentAmount,
     ROUND(runningTotal+currentAmount,2)
    )
   )
  )
 )
}
```

```
={"Balance";
 ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF( ISBLANK(C2:C)*ISBLANK(D2:D),,
   ROUND(
    SUMIF(
     ROW(D2:D),
     "<="&ROW(D2:D),
     D2:D
    ),2
   )
  )
 )
}
```

Comment: `The LAMBDA version seems to work more efficiently with less load on the sheet.` I'm not surprised. One of the "weaknesses" of `ARRAYFORMULA` is that if the range is open (such as "D2:D") then it will apply to **every row** in the column regardless of the number of rows of data. OTOH, a strength of `LAMBDA` is that even if the range is open, it only applies to those rows with data.